# Getting file from URL - error

Tags: java, url, httpconnection, polarion

Thanks to this question( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955624/download-a-file-from-the-internet-using-java-how-to-authenticate) ), I know how to download a file from the internet. However, instead of a normal Text in a txt-file i get a html response. Does anyone know what I'am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
                    // Install Authenticator
                MyAuthenticator.setPasswordAuthentication("Username", "Password");
                Authenticator.setDefault (new MyAuthenticator(Main.getPropertyPath()));

                URL website = new URL("http://.../5-Anhang.txt?revision=1260");
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.txt");
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

**EDITED**

Response:

```
<html>
<body onLoad='document.forms["login"].submit();'>
<form id='login' method='POST' action='/polarion/j_security_check'>
<input type='hidden' name='j_username' value='null'/>
<input type='hidden' name='j_password' value='null'/>
<noscript>
<input type='submit' value="Login"/>
</noscript>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try in this way?         URL url = new URL("http://yourserver.com:80/filename");
        // read text
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
 String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);// Add this line into file output stream
 }
 in.close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since comment is not readable, posting the answer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/js/txt1.txt");
        // read text
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
    }
}
```

Below code worked for to read a text file which is in below format

```
Novak Djokovic
Andy Murray
Roger Federer
Nishokiri
```

Output

> Novak Djokovic
>
> Andy Murray
>
> Roger Federer
>
> Nishokiri

Comment: with this code i get the same output as with mine :/

Comment: I added revision=1260 to txt1.txt in URL as per modified answer and able to get the content. Can you provide me your output ?

Comment: I have added it to my question, sadly i cannot mark you answer as useful, because of my reputation :(

Comment: What is actual content of 5-Anhang.txt? Is it same as of you printed in output?

Comment: Are you getting "Hello" if you remove "?revision=1260" from the URL?

Comment: no i get the exact same response the with "revision=1260"

Comment: I doubt that two copies are present for 5-Anhang.txt file in two different location and other file is picked up from the program. Can you check?

Comment: your are right! Thank you very much. Also "?revision=1260" isn't needed. Can you post a new answer that i can accept?

Comment: Removed revision in answer

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it might me searching for the class "revision=1260" on the webpage and returning that

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That's true however I can't place comments yet, see my rep score :). So I'm just trying to help him out

Comment: Well your reputation won't rise if you post comments as answers and they're downvoted...

Comment: but when i enter the url in my browser the file download window pops up and i can download or open the file

Comment: @prosk what does your browser do when you enter the URL without the "?revision=1260" ?

Comment: i can Download a txt-file, but the content looks weird like ÿØÿá Exif  II*